# Check and take element of another list

Tags: flutter, dart

There is list A and list B. It is necessary to check whether list A contains elements of list B, and if so, then display them.

What I have tried:

```
List<String> profanityList = str.split('\n');

List<String> storyWordList = NewStory.storyController.text.split(' ');

List<String> wordsForChange = [];

for (int i = 0; i < storyWordList.length; i++) 
{
    if (profanityList.contains(storyWordList[i])) 
    {
       wordsForChange.add(storyWordList[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include sample dist data and what you've tried

Comment: @YeasinSheikh, yes already changed.

Comment: Can you include code-snippet instead of code-image

Comment: @YeasinSheikh, yes

Answer (score 0):

**To find common items:** We can use set intersection

```dart
void main(List<String> args) {
  final List<String> listA = List.generate(12, (index) => index.toString());
  final List<String> listB = List.generate(4, (index) => index.toString());
  
  final result = listA.toSet().intersection(listB.toSet()).toList();
  print(result); //[0, 1, 2, 3]
}
```

---

**To find difference  items:**
You can covert list to set and get difference to find difference item.

```dart
void main(List<String> args) {
  final List<String> listA = List.generate(12, (index) => index.toString());
  final List<String> listB = List.generate(4, (index) => index.toString());
  final result = listA.toSet().difference(listB.toSet()).toList();
  print(result); //[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
}
```

Now you can use `result` list to show on UI

Comment: Does not work. If anything, I check the text for obscene language. I translate text into individual words in a sheet. And I also have a text file with all obscene words, and I also translate it into a sheet by individual words. And then I need to check the first sheet for the content of the words from the second one.

Comment: Are you getting `storyWordList` and `storyWordList` well?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't understand

Comment: Are you able to get list of string on `storyWordList` and `storyWordList`. I think I misunderstood the question, 1min

Comment: Try 1st approach of `intersection`